# Нелингвист и не лингвист?

Tags: орфография

Нелингвист не напишет такой диктант;

Он не лингвист.

Почему во втором случае *не* пишется раздельно?

Comment: См. мой ответ тут: http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1447070-v-kakom-sluchae-mozhno-pisat-slitno-slovo-nerusskij.html#answer4231252

Answer (score 5):

doom, действительно есть два варианта написания сочетания "не" с существительными подобного рода (не только обозначающими лиц, но с ними прежде всего). Если все вместе представляет собой новое качество, то написание слитное, если отрицание имеющегося - раздельное.

В первом случае это образование представляет собой подлежащее, там простое отрицание вряд ли возможно.

Во втором возможно и раздельное, и слитное написание, в зависимости от вкладываемого автором смысла. Так что для диктанта это плохой текст.

Answer (score 4):

Пишутся слитно с не существительные, обозначающие лиц и выражающие качественный оттенок; в сочетании с не образуются слова со значением противопоставления. Например: нерусский, неспециалист.

Во втором случае простое отрицание.

Answer (score 3):

В предельно строгом смысле, второму варианту для определённости написания нужен контекст.

`Он не лингвист, а космонавт.`

(частицей "не" отрицается принадлежность к лингвистам)

```
Он нелингвист, угодивший в сообщество лингвистов.
```

(утверждается принадлежность к условной категории людей, не связанных с лингвистикой)

С другой стороны, при отсутствии контекста предложение с написанием "Он нелингвист.", хотя оно и возможно грамматически (в составе соотв. абзаца), несёт странный смысл: вне контекстных условностей *не существует* таких понятий, как "нелингвисты", "некосмонавты" или "негинекологи". Именно поэтому *изолированное* предложение "Он не лингвист." (которое способно нести самостоятельный смысл) **должно** трактоваться как *отрицание принадлежности к лингвистам*  - с соответствующим раздельным написанием.

Answer (score 2):

**ОТРИЦАНИЕ** (в отрицательных предложениях, имеется или подразумевается противопоставление)

Я, конечно, **не лингвист**, но мне кажется, что умная статья - признак ума, а не таланта. 
Кстати, он **не лингвист** (в смысле - специалист по лингвистике, языковед), . Он просто полиглот, человек, которому нравиться изучать языки.

**УТВЕРЖДЕНИЕ**

Есть или подразумевается **сопоставление**: лингвисты и нелингвисты, лингвистика и нелингвисты и т.д). Кроме того, слово часто используется в **утвердительных** конструкциях в функции подлежащего или дополнения

Лингвистика для **нелингвистов**, базовый курс английского язЫка для **нелигвистов**, загадка для **лингвистов и нелингвистов**

Я привожу случаи, которые наблюдал, вероятно, **каждый и нелингвист**, но если заняться систематически регистрацией всех «оговорок» и «обмолвок», то можно записать такие перлы, про которые их авторы будут с ожесточением утверждать, что они никоим образом не могли сказать что-либо подобное (Л. В. Щерба).